Timeout since the migration to angular 18
Since the upgrade to angular18, I'm having timeout with simple component
[vite] Internal server error: Page /guide did not render in 30 seconds.
      at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mbagi\Developer\xxx\angular-client\node_modules\@angular\build\src\utils\server-rendering\render-page.js:90:90)
      at Timeout.timer (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:2320:21)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:459:13)
      at _ZoneImpl.runTask (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:226:35)
      at invokeTask (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:540:14)
      at Timeout.ZoneTask.invoke (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:524:33)
      at Timeout.data.args.<computed> (c:/Users/mbagi/Developer/xxx/angular-client/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:2301:23)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
      at process.processTimers (node: internal/timers:514:7

The component is used to render an image once every second, it takes into parameters the list of images
import { Component, OnInit, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    @if(img(); as img){
      <img [src]="img" />
    }
  `,
  styles: '',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  imgs = ['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/02/03/15/water-8228076_1280.jpg',
  'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/157482223/de/foto/water-splash.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=tovlRmZEzpSmlXEL9OH8iANIK2w16YQD8QDDtsmxs3U=',
  'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/157482222/de/foto/gefrorene-tropfen-wasser.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=ASd2SEWIz7EEiSQLeCdrf6zA-eR9ExAyFCzZLG1tXco='];

  img = signal('');
  intervalId:any;
  pointer=0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.img.set(this.imgs[0]);
    this.startImageRotation();
  }

  startImageRotation(): void {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.pointer = (this.pointer + 1) % this.imgs.length;
      this.img.set(this.imgs[this.pointer]);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

The code is working if I load another page and I navigate to this page, if I try to refresh the page directly there is a TimeOut. However it always fails if I try to run ng build. This page doesn't let me build to the project
How to reproduce the issue in few steps with ANGULAR 18 :
ng new test

Update the app.compenent.ts
import { Component, OnInit, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    @if(img(); as img){
      <img [src]="img" />
    }
  `,
  styles: '',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  imgs = `['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/02/03/15/water-8228076_1280.jpg',
  'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/157482223/de/foto/water-splash.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=tovlRmZEzpSmlXEL9OH8iANIK2w16YQD8QDDtsmxs3U=',
  'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/157482222/de/foto/gefrorene-tropfen-wasser.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=ASd2SEWIz7EEiSQLeCdrf6zA-eR9ExAyFCzZLG1tXco=']`;

  img = signal('');
  intervalId:any;
  pointer=0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.img.set(this.imgs[0]);
    this.startImageRotation();
  }

  startImageRotation(): void {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.pointer = (this.pointer + 1) % this.imgs.length;
      this.img.set(this.imgs[this.pointer]);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

then Serve
ng serve

You should have an error like that


It would be great to have a minimal reproduction with stackblitz or a similar tool. Probably you can also help narrowing down the error by trying to remove some things from the component.

my code is very minimal, unfortunately there is no stackblitz with Angular18 yet. My code  is only crashing with Angular18

Unless someone else has the same issue by chance, this question doesn't have a good chance to be answered in its current state. You could try to create a stackblitz on v17 and then update the Angular dependencies to v18, there shouldn't be any breaking changes for such a simple setup.

Thanks for your comment. I was not able to create the code in stackblitz because v18 is introducing a lot of new stuff, however I have added few steps for reproducing the error

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdyuch?file=src%2Fmain.ts it works with ANgular17

Looks like you're either using ssr or prerendering. Your app remains unstable because of the pending interval.
You could start the interval on the client only with afterNextRender()
afterNextRender(() => {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.pointer = (this.pointer + 1) % this.imgs.length;
      this.img.set(this.imgs[this.pointer]);
    }, 1000);
);


how to solve this ?

Hi Matthieu, I see that you are very knowledgeable in Angular. May I ask you to have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78529401/i18n-with-angular18-tsconfig-server-json-is-removed. I struggle to update my code to make it works with the last version of Angular 18
