i18n with Angular18 - tsconfig.server.json is removed
Since the update to Angular 18, my bi-lingual website is broken.
After the update it removes the tsconfig.server.json and the related scripts that I was running to serve both languages, it also removed a section from angular.json.
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/morefont-v5/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "localize":true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        }

I followed this guide for implementing i18n but since the update there is a lot of errors.
I have tried to create back the tsconfig.server.json but the server/server/mjs is not generated with the build anymore.
my tsconfig.server.json manually replaced in the code after the upgrade
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@angular/localize"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}

my proxy server look like this
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const getTranslatedServer = (lang) => {
  const distFolder = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    `dist/morefont-v5/server/${lang}`
  );
  const server = require(`${distFolder}/main.js`);
  return server.app(lang);
};

function run() {
  const port = 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const appFr = getTranslatedServer("fr");
  const appEn = getTranslatedServer("en");

  const server = express();
  server.use("/fr", appFr);
  server.use("/en", appEn);
  server.use("", appEn);

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();

When I run the serve it crash since server.mjs is not generated anymore
Full angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "morefont-v5": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale":"en",
        "locales": {
          "fr":{
            "translation":"src/i18n/messages-fr.xlf",
            "baseHref": "fr/"
          }
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "pdfmake/build/pdfmake",
              "file-saver",
              "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts"
            ],
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "dist/morefont-v5"
            },
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "localize": ["en","fr"],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": "ngsw-config.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "morefont-v5:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "morefont-v5:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "morefont-v5:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss", "src/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json",
              "tsconfig.server.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "morefont-v5:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "morefont-v5:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}


can you share you current angular.json config ?

done, it seems now that I have to use nginx or something else to serve both language in prod
